# How do I copy music from iphone 4 to iphone 5s and windows computer?

Tags: iphone, itunes, music, windows

I have three devices:

1) iPhone 4 synced with old computer whose hard drive failed

2) iPhone 5s not synced with any computer

3) New windows computer

All of the music (most of it not purchased on itunes) is on the iphone 4.  I want to copy it to the windows computer and the iphone 5s.  I am signed into the same itunes account on all three devices.  When I plug my iphone 4 in, it doesn't let me sync because it is still tied to another computer.  Sadly that other computer is dead and I lost all of the music and it only exists now on the iphone 4.  I tried backing up the iphone 4 and then restoring it to the iphone 5s, but the backup does not contain music.

Any ideas on how to transfer the music off the iphone 4?

Thanks

Comment: This is my father-in-laws music and I'd like to help him out for fathers day.  I've setup a backup solution for him so hopefully this doesn't happen again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[iFunBox](http://www.i-funbox.com/) should allow you to copy the music from any iOS device (jailbroken or not) onto a Windows or Mac computer.

See [this](http://blog.i-funbox.com/?p=869) support article for more relevant information.

Comment: That worked! I was also able to retrieve photos from the phone.